# Assertion failed <dst.data != src.data > in unknown function ../../ocv/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/imgwarp.cpp

Tags: c++, c, image, visual-studio-2010, opencv

Hey please can someone help me to found the solution of this error :

Assertion failed  in unknown function ../../ocv/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/imgwarp.cpp

i try to compile the code that exist in this link : http://ipwithopencv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ThinPlateSpline/ThinPlateSpline/

im using 2 classes and the main:

here is my main code :

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <cv.h>
#include <cxcore.h>
#include <highgui.h>
#include "CThinPlateSpline.h"
#include "iostream"

using namespace std; 

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    // load a nice picture

    cv::Mat img = cv::imread("lena.jpg");

    // generate some generic points
    // usually you would use a interest point detector such as SURF or SIFT
    std::vector<cv::Point> iP, iiP;

    // push some points into the vector for the source image
    iP.push_back(cv::Point(50,50));
    iP.push_back(cv::Point(400,50));
    iP.push_back(cv::Point(50,400));
    iP.push_back(cv::Point(400,400));
    iP.push_back(cv::Point(256,256));
    iP.push_back(cv::Point(150,256));

    // push some point into the vector for the dst image
    iiP.push_back(cv::Point(70,70));
    iiP.push_back(cv::Point(430,60));
    iiP.push_back(cv::Point(60,410));
    iiP.push_back(cv::Point(430,420));
    iiP.push_back(cv::Point(220,280));
    iiP.push_back(cv::Point(180,240));

    // create thin plate spline object and put the vectors into the constructor
    CThinPlateSpline tps(iP,iiP);


    // warp the image to dst
    Mat dst;
    tps.warpImage(img,dst,0.01,INTER_CUBIC,BACK_WARP);


    // show images
    cv::imshow("original",img);
    cv::imshow("distorted",dst);
    //cv::waitKey(0);
    //Sleep(5);
    cv::waitKey(5000); 
    return 0;
}
```

here is the is the imagewarp method :

```
void CThinPlateSpline::warpImage(const Mat& src, Mat& dst, float lambda, const int interpolation,const TPS_INTERPOLATION tpsInter)
{
    Size size = src.size();
    dst = Mat(size,src.type());

    // only compute the coefficients new if they weren't already computed
    // or there had been changes to the points
    if(tpsInter == BACK_WARP && !FLAG_COEFFS_BACK_WARP_SET)
    {
        computeSplineCoeffs(pSrc,pDst,lambda,tpsInter);
    }
    else if(tpsInter == FORWARD_WARP && !FLAG_COEFFS_FORWARD_WARP_SET)
    {
        computeSplineCoeffs(pSrc,pDst,lambda,tpsInter);
    }

    computeMaps(size,mapx,mapy);

    remap(src,dst,mapx,mapy,interpolation);
}
```

there is to other classes that exist in the link also CthinPlateSpline.cpp and CthinPlateSpline.h ...please i really need help and sorry for my bad english

Comment: the code you're showing is not related to the problem. please dig out the src for tps.warpImage()

Comment: [link](http://ipwithopencv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ThinPlateSpline/ThinPlateSpline/CThinPlateSpline.cpp) here is the ThinPlateSplace.cpp Where all definition methods exists

Comment: oh, please edit your question instead, so it gets more readable ;)

Comment: ah ok sorry berrak i have posted the method please see if you detect the error please

Comment: Are you using a picture that is at least 430X420 pixels?

Comment: yes my picture is 500*500 pixels :(

Comment: Compile with debuginfo (`-g`) and you should get a better error message.

Comment: im working with visual studio 2010 on windows i can't found this option i guess that is does'nt exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can run these on my mac with OpenCV 2.4.7

The result image is a twisted lena

I just change two places as following

First of all, I change the included file in main.cpp to become

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include "CThinPlateSpline.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
```

And included file in CThinPlateSpline.cpp to become

```
#include <vector>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include "CThinPlateSpline.h"
```

I use only 3 files main.cpp, CThinPlateSpline.cpp, and CThinPlateSpline.h

libraries linked are

-lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui

Comment: Finally it works dear @maythe4thbewithu i would like to thank you very much for helping me

Comment: So what's the problem with the path ?

Comment: sorry dear maythe4thbewithu for not answering all this time,the problem was with the libs i mixed release and debug libs in visual studio

Answer (score 1):

"Assertion failed" in OpenCV usually happens when your input **Mat** has incorrect size, e.g. zero (empty Mat) or less than the requirement of the function.

Would you mind to check **img** after `cv::Mat img = cv::imread("lena.jpg");`
by img.empty() or display img by imshow?

Comment: thanks maythe4thbewithu i have tried after cv::Mat img = cv::imread("lena.jpg"); this: if(img.empty()==true){ std::cout<<"empty image"<<endl;} the result was empty image ..is the probleme in image location or what exactely ..can you help me please

Comment: @younestheboss  I can run these (main.cpp, CThinPlateSpline.cpp, CThinPlateSpline.h) on my mac with OpenCV 2.4.7, the result image is a  twisted Lena.

Comment: im using opencv2.2 i have always the same problème i try to change the location of image but still have the same error @maythe4thbewithu thanks a lot for ur help

Comment: You should use complete path of the image under Windows imread("C:\\where\\is\\your\\lena.jpg") ;  NOTE:there are two \\ not one \

Comment: I have to offline for 30 min, just put your result or question.

Comment: im using windows...yes i give the complete path and use \\ not \

Comment: ok dear @maythe4thbewithu thanks a lot i will try and put the result

Comment: don't use Chinese/non-English or empty space in your complete path?

Comment: hey dear @maythe4thbewithu i did all necessary things but still have empty image in the test img.empty() i think it has relation with permissions or something :s

Answer (score 0):

Verify if the image was loaded correctly. In my case (OpenCV for Python) my image was not loaded at all.

Try to verify what image exactly are you passing to the function.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ it happens when the source and destination image does not have the save size. In python usually, it happens when the source image is empty, none, etc.